# Audio recorder api

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

Is it possible to record audio at a 16 kHz sampling rate using the Media Recorder API? If the API only supports 48 kHz recording, would resampling the recorded 48 kHz audio to 16 kHz cause any issues for keyword spotting? I'm facing limitations with the API's supported sampling rates, and I'm looking for a workaround to achieve the desired 16 kHz sampling rate for my keyword spotting application.

Comment: "resampling 48 kHz to 16 kHz shouldn't make much, if any, difference than if the original recording was made at 16 kHz. Have you tried and had issues?"

Comment: what does "Media Recorder API" have to do with PHP?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. It seems like you are not familiar with the standards of Stack Overflow regarding questions. Please read following article: [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!